# Should we create a "debug my code" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

As mentioned in my [question about the definition of "debug my code" questions](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question), I'd like to propose that we merge two existing close reasons and make room for a new close reason dedicated to addressing "debug my code" questions.

I'm going to post, as an answer to this question, what I think we should do now based on the general consensus from previous question on the definition. Feel free to upvote that answer or propose your own solution (including a post saying we shouldn't do this, if that's how you feel).

Comment: This is now live!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I propose the merging of our current close reasons that cover "which technology" questions and "what to learn next" questions. For reference, these reasons are currently:

> Questions that are about "which tech to use" are outside the scope of
>   the site. For more information, see [this meta post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/695/)

and

> Questions about "how to get started" or "what should I learn next"
>   cannot reasonably be answered with anything other than opinion polling
>   and therefore are off topic for the site. For more information on how
>   to ask a better question, see the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

---

I suggest we combine them as follows:

> Questions about "how to get started," "what to learn next" or "which
>   technology to use" are discussion-oriented questions which involve
>   answers that are either based on opinion, or which are all equally
>   valid. Visit our [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help)
>   for more information.

and then add the following new close reason:

> Questions about debugging a problem in your
>   project must present a concise selection of code and context so as to allow a
>   reader to diagnose the issue without needing to read
>   *all* of your code or to engage in extensive back-and-forth
>   dialog. For more information, see [this meta
>   thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question)

Comment: I don't know if that should say "to read to read" but it looks like a good idea to me otherwise. :)

Comment: Since we [really are allowed only 3 custom reasons](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/off-topic-variations/1214#1214), I think this is an excellent proposal.

Comment: My only quibble: Can we trim off "on asking questions here", so it's just "Visit our help center for more information."? The help center contains more information not *just* on *asking questions* but also on *why we have such rules*, among many other useful things.

Comment: I was going to ask about why not bring back too localized but based on the opinions in [this meta post](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/there-is-no-point-closing-something-as-too-localized) and the way you've worded your debugging close reason I would say you've really got a good solution here.

Comment: @Anko, I like that idea.

Comment: Looks good to me as well. But if we are going to trim off "on asking questions here", I think there should be a comma after "information".

Comment: I've added the reasons and they are pending approval by another moderator.

Comment: ...and it's now live!